# how to combine three sql selects into one query

Tags: sql

I have the three queries below, I would like to combine them into one query so I get three columns with results by county.  I tried doing an inner join with all of the tables, but I was getting bad data.  How can I combine these three queries and group by County?

```
     select [Total DLL Children] = SUM(cd.NumberOfLanguageSpeakers)
 from ClassroomDLL as cd
 inner join Classrooms as c on cd.Classroom_Id = c.Id
 inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
 inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
 inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
 group by co.Description

 select [Total Children] = (SUM(demo.NumberOfPreschoolers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfInfants))
 from ClassroomDemographics as demo
 inner join Classrooms as c on demo.Classroom_Id = c.Id
 inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
 inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
 inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
 group By co.Description

 select co.Description from Counties as co
 group by co.Description
```

Comment: we need more information than what you have provided

Comment: what information do you need?

Comment: Outputs exepected vice result.  Explain plans.  A SQLFiddle

Comment: outputs expected is in my explanation above.....I don't see how you are not able to understand that.

Comment: Hmm, if it is so easy to understand why are you unable to answer your own question?  This community is for helping others with problems, however since you are clearly a superior being you have no need for us.  The objective is to provide all known information to assist others in getting **you** past **your** issue.

Comment: the question is easy to understand, obviously I wouldn't be posting if I knew the answer.  Amazing how you can't grasp simple explanations.  I have an idea, if you can't figure out the answer, don't post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Basically, each subquery, you need to return County.Description too, then you can join them together.

```
 SELECT A.Description, B.[Total DLL Children], C.[Total Children]
 FROM (
     select co.Description from Counties as co
     group by co.Description
     ) A
 LEFT JOIN 
     (
         select co.Description, [Total DLL Children] = SUM(cd.NumberOfLanguageSpeakers)
         from ClassroomDLL as cd
         inner join Classrooms as c on cd.Classroom_Id = c.Id
         inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
         inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
         inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
         group by co.Description
      ) B
      ON A.DESCRIPTION = B.DESCRIPTION 
LEFT JOIN 
      (
         select co.Description, [Total Children] = (SUM(demo.NumberOfPreschoolers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfInfants))
         from ClassroomDemographics as demo
         inner join Classrooms as c on demo.Classroom_Id = c.Id
         inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
         inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
         inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
         group By co.Description
      ) C
      ON A.DESCRIPTION = C.DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: how can I change it to bring back only columns Having COUNT(c.[Total CHildren] > 0)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to convert your existing queries into inline tables like this - you don't need the select from Counties table as you've already got that table in your first two queries:

```
select co.Description, a.[Total DLL Children], b.[Total Children]
from
(select co.id,[Total DLL Children] = SUM(cd.NumberOfLanguageSpeakers)
 from ClassroomDLL as cd
 inner join Classrooms as c on cd.Classroom_Id = c.Id
 inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
 inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
 inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
 group by co.id, co.Description) a
 join 
 (select co.id, co.Description, [Total Children] = (SUM(demo.NumberOfPreschoolers) +             SUM(demo.NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfInfants))
  from ClassroomDemographics as demo
  inner join Classrooms as c on demo.Classroom_Id = c.Id
  inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
  inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
  inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
  group By co.id, co.Description) b on a.id = b.id
```