# sql queries combined

Tags: sql

I have the three queries below, I would like to combine them into one query so I get three columns with results by county.  I tried doing an inner join with all of the tables, but I was getting bad data.  How can I combine these three queries and group by County?

```
select co.Description
from Counties as co
group by co.Description


select [Total DLL Children] = SUM(cd.NumberOfLanguageSpeakers)
from ClassroomDLL as cd
  inner join Classrooms as c on cd.Classroom_Id = c.Id
  inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
  inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
  inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
group by co.Description


select
  [Total Children] = (SUM(demo.NumberOfPreschoolers)
     + SUM(demo.NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfInfants))
from ClassroomDemographics as demo
  inner join Classrooms as c on demo.Classroom_Id = c.Id
  inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
  inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
  inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
group By co.Description
```

Comment: What flavour of SQL are we talking?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663727/how-to-combine-three-sql-selects-into-one-query

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using subqueries

```
 select co.Description, demo.[Total Children], cd.[Total DLL Children]
 from Classrooms as c
 left outer join (select SUM(NumberOfPreschoolers) + SUM(NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(NumberOfInfants) as [Total Children], Classroom_id 
                    from ClassroomDemographics group by Classroom_id) as demo on demo.Classroom_id = c.Id
 left outer join (select SUM(NumberOfLanguageSpeakers) as [Total DLL Children], Classroom_id 
                    from ClassroomDLL group by Classroom_id) as cd on cd.Classroom_id = c.Id
 inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
 inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
 inner join Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
 group By co.Description
```